# Reducer with typing reported that it can only accept never type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, slice

I'm trying to make a slice with a typed reducer.

First I define IFeatureState and initialState like so:

```
interface IFeatureState {
  content: string;
  open: boolean;
}

const initialState: IFeatureState = {
  content: "",
  open: false,
  
};
```

Then I write the reducer:

```
type StatePayload<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    propName: K;
    value: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];

export default function setState<T>(
  state: T,
  { payload }: PayloadAction<StatePayload<T>>
) {
  state[payload.propName] = payload.value;
}
```

If I try to test this as a function it throws no errors:

```
const statePayload : StatePayload<IFeatureState> = {propName: 'content',value: 'asd'};

const testReducer = setState(initialState, {payload: statePayload, 'type':'...'});

// ok
```

But if you try to create a slice using the function ``createSlice` I got an error:

```
export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setState,
  },
});

appSlice.actions.setState(statePayload);

// Argument of type '{ propName: "content"; value: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`StatePayload<T>` seems overcomplicated, I would simplify it a bit:

```js
type StatePayload<T> = {
  propName: string
  value: T
}
```

now, you need to satisfy generic type here :

```js
const statePayload: StatePayload<boolean> = {
  propName: 'content',
  value: true
}
```

above refactor will satisfy TypeScript, so it no longer complains in example you provided. However if your goal is to have type safety that will be avare that `statePayload.propname` that has string value "open" should also have `statePayload.value` of type boolean and if `statePayload.propname` has value "content" then `statePayload.value` should have type `boolean`... oh boy it is even complicated to wirte down in plain english so let's use TypeScript instead :)

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface IFeatureState {
  content: string
  open: boolean
}

const initialState: IFeatureState = {
  content: '',
  open: false
}

type StatePayload<K extends keyof IFeatureState> = {
  propName: K,
  value: IFeatureState[K]
}

export default function setStateAction(
  state, // state type will be inferred by TS
  { payload }: PayloadAction<StatePayload<'content' | 'open'>>
) {
  state[payload.propName] = payload.value
}

const statePayload: StatePayload<'content'> = {
  propName: 'content',
  value: "STRINNG EXAMPLE"
}

const statePayload2: StatePayload<'open'> = {
  propName: 'open',
  value: true
}

export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setState: setStateAction
  }
})

const testReducer = appSlice.reducer
const { setState } = appSlice.actions

setState(statePayload)
setState(statePayload2)
```

Comment: Okay, I think it works, but I would like to make it more generic.

For example, I would like to use a reducer for other types, similar to StatePayload, but with different keys (in your example, the keys are hardcoded in two places).

Is it possible in typescript?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? One generic reducer for all your state? I'm not sure this is the way to go... In my opinion there is a great power in simplicity. Generic, complicated and hard to understand expressions are more challenging in maintenance while simple ones are easy to deal with... But this is just an opinion, at the end this is tradeof... like everything in software engineering...